# Bash script to remove nested console.log in JS files

Tags: javascript, regex, bash

I have searched and tried methods mentioned in many questions but all methods are taking in consideration only simple use cases. My question is to remove `console.log('some data')` for all below cases.

I need a bash script regex to remove below `console.log()` and keep the rest of the content intact.

`console.log('Some text', variable);`

`console.log('some text with (a) bracket');`

`function myfuncton(console.log('some text with covering bracket'));` to `function myfuncton();`

Note: In the last example, all the content is in single line without any spaces.

I am trying with below regex but it removes all the brackets preceding closing bracket of `console.log`. I know the reason but couldn't figure out the regex.

`SEARCH_STRING="(\/\/)*console.(log|info|warn)\((.*)\)?"`

Do I need to use some other method or it can be done using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a [poor tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2990144) for this job.

You want to use an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

https://github.com/sindresorhus/strip-debug

Comment: I am unable to use strip-debug, its throwing some error related to module import. I will try syntax tree.

Answer (score 0):

If all your `console.log` occurrences are in the form described in the question, you could simply use a regex like `console\.(?:log|info|warn)\('[^']*'(?:,[^)]*)?\);?`, but Seth Holladay's approach is indeed safer.